# Dynamically load EntityType field according to selection on ChoiceType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hey so I'm trying to dynamically load my EntityType data after I selected a choice in my ChoiceType. If both of those dropdowns have been selected, I want to show the rest of the form.

Could someone help me out making this, or link me an example?

My code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\CivilianCriminalRecords;
use App\Entity\FineTypes;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CivilianCriminalRecordsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('fineTypeCategory', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => "Categorie type overtreding",
            'choices'  => [
                'Category 0' => 0,
                'Category 1' => 1,
                'Category 2' => 2,
                'Category 3' => 3,
                'Category 4' => 4,
                'Category 5' => 5,
            ],
        ]);

        // Load when fineTypeCategory is selected.
        $builder->add('offenceType', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => FineTypes::class,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('ft')
                    ->where('ft.category = :categoryId')
                    ->setParameter('categoryId', '0'); // Shouldn't be 0 but the id filled in the fineTypeCategory field.
            },
            'choice_label' => 'label',
        ]);

        // Load when fineTypeCategory AND offenceType is selected
        $builder
            ->add('offence', TextareaType::class, ['label' => 'Omschrijving van de overtreding', 'attr' => ['rows' => '5']])
            ->add('statement', TextareaType::class, ['label' => 'Verklaring van de overtreder', 'attr' => ['rows' => '5']])
            ->add('jailed', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => 'Gevangenisstraf ontvangen?'])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Overtreding uitschrijven'])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => CivilianCriminalRecords::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. It is not tested, but you should see the idea.
I don't know how your controller looks like, but something like this I think:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request): Response
{
    //Get your entity
    $records = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CivilianCriminalRecords::class)->find($id);
    $options['show_offence_type'] = !empty($request->request->get('fineTypeCategory'));
    $options['show_more_params'] = !empty($request->request->get('offenceType'));
    $form = $this->createForm(CivilianCriminalRecordsType::class, $records, $options);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if(
        $request->request->has('offence') && //means that the third part was visible and filled in
        $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        //process the form
    }
    return $this->render('form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'show_offence_type' => $options['show_offence_type'],
        'show_more_params' => $options['show_more_params']
    ]);
}
```

Then the FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder->add('fineTypeCategory', ChoiceType::class, [
        'label' => "Categorie type overtreding",
        'choices'  => [
            'Category 0' => 0,
            'Category 1' => 1,
            'Category 2' => 2,
            'Category 3' => 3,
            'Category 4' => 4,
            'Category 5' => 5,
        ],
    ]);
    if($options['show_offence_type']){
        // Load when fineTypeCategory is selected.
        $builder->add('offenceType', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => FineTypes::class,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('ft')
                    ->where('ft.category = :categoryId')
                    ->setParameter('categoryId', '0'); // Shouldn't be 0 but the id filled in the fineTypeCategory field.
            },
            'choice_label' => 'label',
        ]);
    }
    if($options['show_more_params']){
        // Load when fineTypeCategory AND offenceType is selected
        $builder
            ->add('offence', TextareaType::class, ['label' => 'Omschrijving van de overtreding', 'attr' => ['rows' => '5']])
            ->add('statement', TextareaType::class, ['label' => 'Verklaring van de overtreder', 'attr' => ['rows' => '5']])
            ->add('jailed', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => 'Gevangenisstraf ontvangen?']);
    }
    $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Overtreding uitschrijven']);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => CivilianCriminalRecords::class,
        'show_offence_type' => false,
        'show_more_params' => false
    ]);
}
```

And the template should be like this (only relevant part here):

```
{% if show_offence_type %}
    {{ form_row(form.offenceType) }}
{% endif %}
{% if show_more_params %}
    {{ form_row(form.offence) }}
    {{ form_row(form.statement) }}
    {{ form_row(form.jailed) }}
{% endif %}
```

The idea is to configure and render the input fields only when the form was submitted with the very fist selection. After that, show the next selection and let the user send the form again. Then your show the rest of the form. At the end, when all parts of the form were filled, you can process the form. Happy testing!

Comment: That only hides the elements, not the labels nor surrounding divs, but I see what you're trying to do, I'll see if I can figure something out with this.